# ObjectAnimator xml repeatCount and repeatMode attributes do not work

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

when I want to repeatCount and repeatMode in my object animators it didn't work. Here is my code:

scale.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:ordering="together">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueFrom="1.0f"
        android:valueTo="1.5f"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/bounce"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueFrom="1.0f"
        android:valueTo="1.5f"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/bounce"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```

This code scale some elements of my SplashScreen, they grow once as expected, but the animation does not reverse. I also saw that animator is better than use animation, should I use animation because animator doesn't work well?

Update:

my_animated_vector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_moon">

    <target
        android:animation="@animator/scale"
        android:name="crater" />

</animated-vector>
```

ic_moon.xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="109dp"
    android:height="109dp"
    android:viewportWidth="109"
    android:viewportHeight="109">
    <path android:pathData="M54.5,54.5m-54.5,0a54.5,54.5 0,1 1,109 0a54.5,54.5 0,1 1,-109 0">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient
                android:endX="54.5"
                android:endY="109"
                android:startX="54.5"
                android:startY="0"
                android:type="linear">
                <item
                    android:color="#3FFFFFFF"
                    android:offset="0" />
                <item
                    android:color="#00FFFFFF"
                    android:offset="0.75" />
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
    <group android:name="crater"
        android:pivotX="56"
        android:pivotY="19">
        <path
            android:fillAlpha="0.25"
            android:pathData="M56,19m-7,0a7,7 0,1 1,14 0a7,7 0,1 1,-14 0">
            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                <gradient
                    android:centerX="56"
                    android:centerY="19"
                    android:gradientRadius="7"
                    android:type="radial">
                    <item
                        android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:offset="0.505208" />
                    <item
                        android:color="#FF130909"
                        android:offset="0.854167" />
                </gradient>
            </aapt:attr>
        </path>
    </group>
    <group android:name="crater"
        android:pivotX="28"
        android:pivotY="36">
        <path
            android:fillAlpha="0.25"
            android:pathData="M28,36m-4,0a4,4 0,1 1,8 0a4,4 0,1 1,-8 0">
            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                <gradient
                    android:centerX="28"
                    android:centerY="36"
                    android:gradientRadius="4"
                    android:type="radial">
                    <item
                        android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:offset="0.505208" />
                    <item
                        android:color="#FF130909"
                        android:offset="0.854167" />
                </gradient>
            </aapt:attr>
        </path>
    </group>
    <group android:name="crater"
        android:pivotX="80"
        android:pivotY="66">
        <path
            android:fillAlpha="0.25"
            android:pathData="M80,66m-4,0a4,4 0,1 1,8 0a4,4 0,1 1,-8 0">
            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                <gradient
                    android:centerX="80"
                    android:centerY="66"
                    android:gradientRadius="4"
                    android:type="radial">
                    <item
                        android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:offset="0.505208" />
                    <item
                        android:color="#FF130909"
                        android:offset="0.854167" />
                </gradient>
            </aapt:attr>
        </path>
    </group>
    <group android:name="crater"
        android:pivotX="80"
        android:pivotY="24">
        <path
            android:fillAlpha="0.25"
            android:pathData="M80,24m-4,0a4,4 0,1 1,8 0a4,4 0,1 1,-8 0">
            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                <gradient
                    android:centerX="80"
                    android:centerY="24"
                    android:gradientRadius="4"
                    android:type="radial">
                    <item
                        android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:offset="0.505208" />
                    <item
                        android:color="#FF130909"
                        android:offset="0.854167" />
                </gradient>
            </aapt:attr>
        </path>
    </group>
    <group android:name="crater"
        android:pivotX="84"
        android:pivotY="43">
        <path
            android:fillAlpha="0.25"
            android:pathData="M84,43m-5,0a5,5 0,1 1,10 0a5,5 0,1 1,-10 0">
            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                <gradient
                    android:centerX="84"
                    android:centerY="43"
                    android:gradientRadius="5"
                    android:type="radial">
                    <item
                        android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:offset="0.505208" />
                    <item
                        android:color="#FF130909"
                        android:offset="0.854167" />
                </gradient>
            </aapt:attr>
        </path>
    </group>
    <group android:name="crater"
        android:pivotX="24"
        android:pivotY="56">
        <path
            android:fillAlpha="0.25"
            android:pathData="M24,56m-5,0a5,5 0,1 1,10 0a5,5 0,1 1,-10 0">
            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                <gradient
                    android:centerX="24"
                    android:centerY="56"
                    android:gradientRadius="5"
                    android:type="radial">
                    <item
                        android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:offset="0.505208" />
                    <item
                        android:color="#FF130909"
                        android:offset="0.854167" />
                </gradient>
            </aapt:attr>
        </path>
    </group>
    <group android:name="crater"
        android:pivotX="52"
        android:pivotY="51">
        <path
            android:fillAlpha="0.25"
            android:pathData="M52,51m-7,0a7,7 0,1 1,14 0a7,7 0,1 1,-14 0">
            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                <gradient
                    android:centerX="52"
                    android:centerY="51"
                    android:gradientRadius="7"
                    android:type="radial">
                    <item
                        android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
                        android:offset="0.505208" />
                    <item
                        android:color="#FF130909"
                        android:offset="0.854167" />
                </gradient>
            </aapt:attr>
        </path>
    </group>
</vector>
```

Update2:

MyComposeFile:

```
val moonAnimated = animatedVectorResource(id = R.drawable.animated_moon)
            var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

            Image(
                painter = moonAnimated.painterFor(atEnd = atEnd),
                contentDescription = "Moon",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(maxWidth / (7 / 2), maxHeight / (15 / 2))
                    .constrainAs(moon) {
                        top.linkTo(stars.bottom)
                        start.linkTo(squizzelle.start, maxWidth / 13)
                    }
            )

            DisposableEffect(Unit) {
                atEnd = atEnd.not()
                onDispose {  }
            }
```

Note: I use maxWidth and maxHeight from BoxConstraints to have a responsive layout and handle all screen sizes.

Comment: The animator set looks ok. Post your code that invokes it and anything else that touches it that may be helpful.